# How can I get values from a database according to some fieldname?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, module

I have a custom table in my database with three fields ie `id` `a_id` and `cat_id`

I have an entry like this in the table.

```
    id a_id c_id

    2   7   7
    3   7   8
    4   7   8
    5   7   8
    6   7   5
    7   7   5
    9   9   7
    10  9   5
    11  7   5
```

Now I want to fetch data according to an `a_id` so that all the values will be collect in an array.

I tried this

```
 $categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('a_id','7');
```

but this shows an array without any value in it.

I want to update the table with the form so when I use this code

```
$categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')->load('7');
```

it only shows the last value of the table.

and when I collect this in an array again it only shows the last value.

So how can I collect all the value of the `a_id = 7` in one array.

Here is my model file

```
class Vertax_Blog_Model_Mysql4_Category extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
 public function _construct()
 {
  $this->_init('blog/category','id');
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you get data correctly from collection?

It should be like this

```
 $categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('blog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('a_id','7');
foreach ($categoryCollection as $categoryModel) {
    //row data will be here
    $categoryData = $categoryModel->getData();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it only shows the last value of the table. may be it is overriding all the values and only showing the last one.

Comment: What is the result of `$categoryCollection->getSize()`?

Comment: it is showing an error that ""Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object""

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump(Mage::getModel('blog/category')
    ->getCollection())`

Comment: its a very big data, I don't know what it is called, but its a magento raw data.
object(Vertax_Blog_Model_Mysql4_Category_Collection)#300 (34) {
  ["_model":protected]=>
  string(13) "blog/category"
  ["_resourceModel":protected]=>
  string(13) "blog/category"
  ["_resource":protected]=>

Comment: Hey... thanks. I got the data now. thanks very much.

Comment: I am happy to help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12994/discussion-between-waseem-and-oleksii-svarychevskyi)

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple  Try the Below code.

```
$categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('a_id', array('eq' => 7));
```

For More Reference Visit [fishpig](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/addattributetofilter/)

Comment: I already try this but it shows an error
    Fatal error: Call to undefined method Vertax_Blog_Model_Mysql4_Category_Collection::addAttributeToFilter()

Comment: try this addFieldToFilter()

Comment: I also tried this, I mention this in the question also. but nothing is happen it shows an array.

Comment: this extension Collection has no method  Vertax_Blog_Model_Mysql4_Category_Collection 

so I think you need to check this extension Model Folder Filees.

Comment: I have this file in the model folder, I am attaching it in the question see above.

Comment: I didn't see any folder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12990/discussion-between-waseem-and-keyul-shah)